# What does the "configuration protection" mode do on Yubikeys?

Tags: yubikey

I can't seem to find any documentation on what these options do:

[image]

Does this somehow offer more protection to your secret key? That is all I can think it would do.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=yubikey+configuration+protection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the YubiCo docs: "To protect against unauthorized update of a specific configuration, a protection access code can be added. Then, in order to update or remove this configuration, the corresponding access code must be used, otherwise the request is rejected."